# Cannot catch send() failure with OpenAL

Tags: c, sockets, openal

I have a problem catching a moment on a client side when client is sending data in a loop and server unexpectedly shuts down.

When I'm sending random 1024 byte chunks, everything works well and the program prints "disconnected" on server shutdown.

```
while (1) {
    if (send(sock, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0) < 0) {
        printf("disconnected\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

But when I add OpenAL routines to send captured samples, the loop works the same and data are sent, but on server shutdown, the programs just exits on failed send() without giving any error and executing further code.

```
while (1) {
    alcGetIntegerv(device, ALC_CAPTURE_SAMPLES, (ALCsizei)sizeof(ALint), &samples);
    if (samples > 0) {
        buffer = realloc(buffer, samples);
        alcCaptureSamples(device, buffer, samples);
        if (send(sock, buffer, samples, 0) < 0) {
            printf("disconnected\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what could cause the difference?

Answer (score 0):

With regards to this line:

```
buffer = realloc(buffer, samples);
```

My psychic powers suggest you are invoking `realloc` to size `buffer` to be exactly large enough to hold a count of `samples` bytes.  But the format of the data is larger than 8-bits per sample.   And it's never making it to the send call. It's crashing on the `alcCaptureSamples` call that is writing past the last valid index of your buffer array.

For example, if you are recording in 16-bit stereo, you'd want to allocate a buffer that is of size `samples * 2 * 2`.  Further, when you `send`, you'd want to use this same length as well.

Comment: I am capturing in MONO8, so the code works OK. The only issue I have is catching the "disconnected" event.